# Why am I seeing version numbers that shouldn't exist for my Android app?

Tags: android

My app has an option to send support email, which auto-includes the app version at the bottom of the email. Occasionally I get email with a version that doesn't exist. For example the current version of the app is 2.2 and I may get a support email that says version 2.2.9. In addition, I'm using Crashlytics, which also shows the extra versions.

My assumption is that they are pirated versions but I don't know for sure and was hoping for a second opinion before I respond to or ignore those support emails.

Comment: how are u getting the app version in code through package manager or hard code?

Comment: then u are right those are pirated version of your app

Comment: should i write this is an answer

Comment: yeah go ahead and I'll accept it, thanks. It seems like the only likely explanation. I wonder why they even bother to change the version number though.

Comment: There're two things in version, 1 is `versionName` which is shown to users and the other is `versionCode` that's typically for developers. The extra 9 can be your `versionCode`. Which is increased every time you upload a version, crashlytics always consider this part of full version as 2.2 version and build 9. Making it 2.2.9

Comment: @AdilSoomro got a good point here. His explanation seems far more apt than someone trying to pirate your app. Just saying. Do consider this option and cross check.

Comment: Good point @AdiSoomro and SajibAcharya. In the email I only show versionName, not versionCode. Crashlytics shows the version code in parenthesis after the versionName. I do think they're pirated versions. I know there are pirated versions out there, I've seen them, I just wasn't sure if this was a manifestation of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what u said,somebody pirating your apps and changing app version is the only possible outcome i could think of.

For making it harder for app piracting u could use Proguard